# Show differentiabillity

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I'm trying to show that $f(x)=\sum_1^{\infty}1/n^x$ is differentiable at where it converges(which i found out is x>1). Any ideas on how to do it? I've tried to show by definition but i get lost there.

Comment: There's a theorem about term-by-term differentiation of a series: if the series converges pointwise and its term-by-term derivative is uniformly convergent, then the series is differentiable and its derivative is its term-by-term derivative. You'll want to apply this result on intervals of the form $[A,+\infty)$ with $A>1$. See [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability) for sequences of functions that has a straightforward adaption for series of functions.

Comment: Yeah, i was kind of hoping to avoid this theorem, because the next question was to to show that it uniformly converges at x>1, so i think they meant another way. I might be wrong though and it's the only way. I'm only trying to fish for other ideas.

Comment: The theorem is about uniform convergence of the _term-by-term derivative,_ not about uniform convergence of the series of functions. By the way, the series doesn't converge uniformly on $(1,+\infty)$, only on subsets included in intervals of the form $[A,+\infty)$ with $A>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n \in \mathbb N$, $x>1$ and $h \in \mathbb R$ with $x+h >1$ there exists $c \in (x,x+h)$ such that
$$\frac{1}{n^{x+h}}-\frac{1}{n^x}+\frac{\ln n}{n^x}h=\frac{\ln^2 n}{n^c}\frac{h^2}{2}$$ This is Taylor's theorem.

Hence for $\vert h \vert < \frac{x-1}{2}$ you get
$$\left\vert \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n^x} \right\vert \le \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln^2 n}{n^{\frac{x+1}{2}}}\right) \frac{\vert h \vert}{2}$$

Letting $h \to 0$, you get that $f$ is differentiable with 
$f^\prime(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n^x}$